# No data stores are configured for MVC application using Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Created an MVC application using framework 6 & ASP.NET vNext.

Application looks for a database table using the Entity Framework. The connection string which is present in config.json file is not readable from application reporting back the exception below.

## EXCEPTION

> "No data stores are configured. Configure a data store using On Configuring or by creating an ImmutableDbContextOptions with a data store configured and passing it to the context."

## config.json

```
{
"Data": {
"DefaultConnection": {
"Context": "Server=     .;Database=Database1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
                              }
        }
}
```

## startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IBuilder app)
{

// Setup configuration sources
var configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.AddJsonFile("config.json");
configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

// Set up application services
app.UseServices(services =>
{
// Add EF services to the services container
services.AddEntityFramework()
.AddSqlServer();

// Configure DbContext
services.SetupOptions<DbContextOptions>(options =>
{
options.UseSqlServer(configuration.Get("Data:DefaultConnection:Context")    );
});

// Add Identity services to the services container
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
.AddEntityFramework<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddHttpSignIn();

// Add MVC services to the services container
services.AddMvc();
});

// Enable Browser Link support
app.UseBrowserLink();

// Add static files to the request pipeline
app.UseStaticFiles();

// Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Details"),
});
```

This maybe related to the Identity Context.

Thank you for any advice.

- sql server 2008
- MVC6
- asp.net vNext

Comment: Paste your code from VS with 4 spaces indent. This is not readable.

Comment: Thanks you for the tip re "4 spaces indent" could not figure out how to deploy that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured a data store by creating an DbContext with a data store configured and passing it to the context.

```
public TestContext(IServiceProvider serviceProvider,        IOptionsAccessor<TestDbContextOptions> optionsAccessor)
: base(serviceProvider, optionsAccessor.Options)
{
       if (!_created)
       {
                   Database.EnsureCreated();
                  _created = true;
        }
}
```

Resolved my issue thanks.